# Publish a collections and other collection's documents which have relation with any document in the first collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

The scenario is that I want to publish one whole collection and users' data (such as profile) who have relation with any document in the the first collection.
The problem is how can I publish that part of users collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) solved my problem completly.
Example:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('getItemsList', {
find: function() {
    return Items.find({});
},
children: [
    {
        find: function(item) {
            return Meteor.users.find(
                { _id: item.userId },);
        }
    }
]});
```

This will publish all the items documents with any user document that have a relation with it. ( Items.userId is mapped to Meteor.users._id )

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways, first is using package

https://atmospherejs.com/cottz/publish-with-relations

And second one - in publish function you can return multiple cursors, from [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)

```
Meteor.publish("roomAndMessages", function (roomId) {
  check(roomId, String);
  return [
    Rooms.find({_id: roomId}, {fields: {secretInfo: 0}}),
    Messages.find({roomId: roomId})
  ];
});
```

Comment: I guess you didn't understand me right. this will return only the messages that have the same roomId. Let me tell you the problem by using your collections. Suppose I published the whole Rooms document. The problem is how to publish the Messages documents which have only relation with Rooms collection.

Comment: That you will do with this package I posted, and the code is pasted from Meteor docs showing that you can publish many collections with one publish

Comment: Can you explain how to use this package?

Comment: There are examples written, you didn't describe much of ur problem so there isnt much I can say